# jQuery linking to other pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Using jQuery mobile I'm creating a simple form that displays a collapsible list of car brands.  Under this collapsible list will be the different models of the car brand. When one clicks/touches the car model, I want to be able to load to another page that will display some statistics of the certain car model. I'm not quite sure how to link to another page/HTML file. This is what I have so far:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
a.test {
font-weight: bold;
        }
        </style>
        <title>My Page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    <!-- view port sets the bar as wide as the screen -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile- 1.3.2.min.css" />
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js">        </script>
    </head>
       <body>
        <div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Dream Ride</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
        <h1>Honda</h1>
          //code to link to other HTML files or pages
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
        <h3>BMW</h3>
        <p>sdfsdf</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
        <h3>Mercedez</h3>
        <p>sdfsdf</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
        <h3>Audi</h3>
        <p>sdfsdf</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
        <h3>Ferrari</h3>
        <p>sdfsdf</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-collapsed-icon="arrow-d" data-expanded-icon="arrow-u">
        <h3>Lamborghini</h3>
        <p>sdfsdf</p>
    </div>

    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>My Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your talking about loading a page without reloading the whole document. To do that with jQuery Mobile create another `<div data-role="page">` and give it an id attribute. In your first page just link to it with an anchor tag: `<a href="#pageid"></a>`

Example:

```
<div data-role="page" id="one">
    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>Page One</h1>
        <a href="#two">Go to page two</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="two">
    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>Page Two</h1>
        <a href="#one">Go to page one</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demonstration on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VaeCL/

Comment: You sir are correct! I was using <div data-role='button'. Just out of curiosity, would it be possible to use button?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just add `data-role="button"` to the `a` tag. `<a href="#one" data-role="button">page one</a>`